# Is it possible to get dimensions values from a specific layer from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, getcapabilities

I'm trying to get values from the dimensions I have inside my layers. Is there any request available in GeoServer API to get thoses values ?

Example : `<Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601"/> <Dimension name="LEVEL" units=""/> <Extent name="time" default="current">2020-01-01T03:00:00.000Z,2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z,2020-01-01T09:00:00.000Z</Extent> <Extent name="LEVEL" default="140.0">140,155,170,206,250,301,350,400,500,600,700</Extent>`

This is an extract from my WMS getCapabilities. I would like to get values in "Extent" tag for "time" and "LEVEL".

Comment: I do not understand. You have the time values `2020-01-01T03:00:00.000Z,2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z,2020-01-01T09:00:00.000Z` and levels `140,155,170,206,250,301,350,400,500,600,700` so what do you miss?

Comment: Yes, actually I would like to get thoses values for one specific layer. And the thing is that getCapabilities return values for all the layers and take several seconds to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using the [WMTS Multidimensial extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/wmts-multidimensional/index.html), which adds extra requests to the WMTS protocol that can be used to explore the dimensions, their contents,  and their relationships.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the dimension values of a layer other than by a `getCapabilities` request. If this is a problem because your capabilities response is very large and hard to parse you can make use of the GeoServer vendor extensions and specify just the [name of the workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#namespace) you want to limit the number of layers returned.